# Parse string with bash and extract number

Tags: regex, bash, unix, parsing

I've got supervisor's status output, looking like this.

```
frontend                         RUNNING    pid 16652, uptime 2:11:17
nginx                            RUNNING    pid 16651, uptime 2:11:17
redis                            RUNNING    pid 16607, uptime 2:11:32
```

I need to extract nginx's PID. I've done it via grep -P command, but on remote machine grep is build without perl regular expression support.

Looks like sed or awk is exactly what I need, but I don't familiar with them.

Please help me to find a way how to do it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
sed 's/.*pid \([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: In order for this to work you'll need to specify the option to enable extended regular expressions. This is usually '-r' (GNU sed) or '-E' (BSD sed). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637799/sed-error-invalid-reference-1-on-s-commands-rhs

Answer (score 8):

Using AWK alone:

```
awk -F'[ ,]+' '{print $4}' inputfile
```

Comment: Works great with a pipe: `$ status |grep nginx |awk -F'[ ,]+' '{print $4}'  -`

Comment: @Keith: It's not necessary to pipe `grep` into `awk`. AWK can do it all by itself: `status | awk -F'[ ,]+' '/nginx/ {print $4}'`

Answer (score 7):

```
$ cat $your_output | sed -s 's/.*pid \([0-9]\+\),.*/\1/'
16652
16651
16607
```

Comment: This is known as a UUOC (Useless use of cat)

Comment: @mikerobi : that was just an example of how to pipe stuff into the command... he didn't say how he had his output... but whatever.

Answer (score 6):

Solution with awk and cut

```
vinko@parrot:~$ cat test
frontend                         RUNNING    pid 16652, uptime 2:11:17
nginx                            RUNNING    pid 16651, uptime 2:11:17
redis                            RUNNING    pid 16607, uptime 2:11:32
vinko@parrot:~$ awk '{print $4}' test | cut -d, -f 1
16652
16651
16607
```

for nginx only:

```
vinko@parrot:~$ grep nginx test | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d, -f 1
16651
```

Comment: there's no need to use awk + cut + grep. Just awk will do the job.
`awk -F"," '/nginx/{print $1}' file`

Comment: @ghostdog74: your command outputs "nginx          RUNNING    pid 16651". The correct awk only solution is in the answer by Dennis (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045493/parse-string-with-bash-and-extract-number/3045718#3045718), using -F '[ ,]+' instead of -F ','

Comment: @vinko, its either that, or just use gsub() to get rid of the comma for awk versions that does not support multiple field delimiters. I am just highlighting the point that awk can do the job and there's no need to use other tools.

Comment: @ghostdog74: Right, you can do it with awk only.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [pgrep](http://code.google.com/p/pgrep/), a variant of grep specially tailored for grepping process tabless.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the grep implementation supports the `-o` option, you could use two greps:

```
output \
  | grep -o '^nginx[[:space:]]\+[[:upper:]]\+[[:space:]]\+pid [0-9]\+' \
  | grep -o '[0-9]\+$'
```