# sed error: "invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS"

Tags: regex, sed, substitution

I run several substitution commands as the core of a [colorize script for maven](https://gist.github.com/johnjohndoe/5337476).
One of the `sed` commands uses a regular expression which works find in the shell as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637432/sed-error-invalid-range-end). The current (not working) implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/johnjohndoe/5337476#file-colorize-maven-sh-L103).

When I include one of the variants of the command into the script different behavior occurs:

**Variant 1:**

```
$ sed -re "s/([a-zA-Z0-9./\\ :-]+)/\1/g"
```

**Adapted to the script:**

```
-re "s/WARNING: ([a-zA-Z0-9./\\ :-]+)/${warn}WARNING: \1${c_end}/g" \
```

**Error:** The shell outputs the same information as if I would type `$ sed`. Strange!?

---

**Variant 2:**

```
$ sed -e "s/\([a-zA-Z0-9./\\ :-]\+\)/\1/g"
```

**Adapted to the script:**

```
-e "s/WARNING: \([a-zA-Z0-9./\\ :-]\+\)/${warn}WARNING: \1${c_end}/g" \
```

**Error:**

> sed: -e expression #7, char 59: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: In my case I had combined a `-i` (edit in place option) with `-re`, resulting in `-ire` (so that `-i` was consuming the `re` fragment as its `SUFFIX` argument and hence the extended regex mode was not being enabled); changing it to `-i -re` fixed the issue.

Comment: It's also to notice that single quotes `'` and double quotes `"` are treated slightly different, especially when interpreting `$vars`. For example: `sudo sh -c "sed -r -i 's/(^.+_supplicant.conf)/\1${MTXT}/' /etc/network/interfaces"` works, but: `sudo sh -c 'sed -r -i "s/(^.+_supplicant.conf)/\1${MTXT}/" /etc/network/interfaces'` does not.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Don't you need to actually capture for that to work? i.e. for variant #2:

```
-r -e "s/WARNING: (\([a-zA-Z0-9./\\ :-]\+\))/${warn}WARNING: \1${c_end}/g" \
```

(Note: untested)

Without the `-r` argument back-references (like `\1`) won't work unless each parenthesis is escaped with a `\` character.

With `-r`, argument back-references (like `\1`) won't work unless the parenthesis are NOT escaped.

Comment: The `-r` option to sed appears to be necessary for the back-reference to work.  E.g `sed -e 's/([[:digit:]])/is a digit/'` works but `sed -e 's/([[:digit:]])/\1 is a digit/` produces the original error without `-r` to sed.  **NOTE:** the first invocation of sed searches for a literal `(<digit>)` and **is not** a capture group.

Comment: The comment below the answer is actually an answer. Maybe you can edit your answer to reflect it.

Comment: @AndrewFalanga you should have posted your comment as an answer

Comment: Nevermind my mistake was to use `-ire` instead of use `-ri`. Order matters :-)

Comment: `-r, --regexp-extended` = `use extended regular expressions in the script.` In most current versions the `-E` and `-r` both can be used. Extended as opposed to basic.

Answer (score 63):

This error is common for parentheses that are not escaped. Escape them and try again.

---

For example:

```
/^$/b
:loop
$!{
N
/\n$/!b loop
}
s/\n(.)/\1/g
```

Should be escaped with backslashes before each parenthesis:

```
/^$/b
:loop
$!{
N
/\n$/!b loop
}
s/\n\(.\)/\1/g
```

Comment: Attention, if you use `-r` you don't have to escape the parentheses.

Answer (score 36):

If the `-r`/`--regexp-extended` option is not provided, then the capturing parentheses must be escaped.

Answer (score 8):

You need escape the `/` after the `.`

```
sed -e "s/\([a-zA-Z0-9.\/\\ :-]\+\)/\1/g"
```

Or if you don't want to worry about escaping, use `|`

```
sed -e "s|\([a-zA-Z0-9./\\ :-]\+\)|\1|g"
```

EDIT:

```
sed -e "s|WARNING: \([a-zA-Z0-9.-/\\ :]+\)|${warn}WARNING: \1${c_end}|g"
```

Comment: Sound reasonable. But it does not work in the context of the script.

Comment: Sorry. The edit raises the error: `sed: -e expression #7, char 58: Invalid range end`. @Denis' answer works.

Comment: Ok, then +1 for @Denis' answer