# Sed match ^ NOT operand with .* anyString Matches

Tags: regex, variables, sed

***Please, if you could incorporate your answer into a working sed line.***

Solution:

```
sed -r "s/([^]].*)\[/\1\r[/g" testfile.txt
```

Solution that handles both sides of the bracket, and removes tabs

```
sed -r "s/\t//g;s/([^]].*)\[/\1\r[/g;s/\]([^[].*)$/]\r\1/g" testfile.txt
```

I have this gnuwin32 (working) sed line:

```
sed -r "s/(.*)\[/\1\r[/g" testfile.txt
```

What it does is

```
s/
(.*)\[  - matches anyString[
/
\1\r[   - splits anyString<INSERTSCARRIAGERETURN>[
/g
```

What I'd like to do is use a ^ (NOT Operand) to exclude anyString from being a "]"

so...

before is pretty much this

```
*[
```

becomes

```
*
[
```

however...

if `* == ]`, I'd like to not perform the operation.

It was suggested I do something like `^\[`

However I don't know where/how to implement the `^` operator on a variable stringMask such as `(.*)`.  Does `.*` being a string matter when I'm trying to text if `*` is/ends with `]`?

I'm thinking either

```
(.*^\[)
```

or

```
(.*)^\[
```

any help would be appreciated.

Here's my sample data set

```
item_gloves

[OBJECT:ITEM]

###test###
    [ITEM_GLOVES:ITEM_GLOVES_GAUNTLETS]###test###
[NAME:gauntlet:gauntlets]
###test###[ARMORLEVEL:2]
[UPSTEP:1]
###test###[SHAPED]
[LAYER:ARMOR]###test######test###
[COVERAGE:100]
[LAYER_SIZE:20]
[LAYER_PERMIT:15]
[MATERIAL_SIZE:2]
[SCALED]
[BARRED]
[METAL]
[LEATHER]
[HARD]
```

Comment: You need to escape last `[`

Comment: Why don't you just use a non-greedy regexp? `(.*?)`

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `([^]]*)`

Comment: because i'm A NEWB!  And I don't know anything.  I just learned how to hold a var into \1 today!

Comment: You should have added this extra requirement [to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363766/read-variable-matched-by-a-operation) instead of posting another. We can work with you if you stay on one question and add such requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -r "s/^([^]]*)\[/\1\r[/g" testfile.txt
```

Comment: that works.  I don't suppose you could recommend how I would do the same with ]*?  Something like sed -r "s/\]^([^[]*)/\]\r\n\1/g" testfile.txt

Comment: `"s/^([^[]*)\]/\1\r]/g"`?

Comment: alas, that was not it.  However, I will try to analyze your solution, and see if I can figure it out.  I just don't understand how the ^ operator works.  I see it listed twice in the sed statement, something like \]^(*[^[])....sed -r "s/\]^(*[^[])/\]\r\n\1/g" testfile.txt

Comment: ]* to be split as ]NEWLINE*; but not if * == [, same problem, but with ]* vs original problem which was reversed

Comment: So, swap around: `s/^\]([^[]+)$/]\r\1/g`

Comment: You _do_ know BTW that `^` means _start of line_ anywhere outside `[]` character ranges?

Comment: idkw, but with the same data, I have some lines as ###comments###, that are to the right of ] that is not getting separated.

Comment: That's because I anchored it to start of line as per your first example (see? to little simple in- & output). Could you try around a bit on http://regex101.com/ & link an example of what you really want of in- & output, and your best effort in making that happen?

Comment: thanks that worked!: sed -r "s/\]([^[]+)$/]\r\n\1/g" testfile.txt... I updated the original post with source data.