# Invalid reference \1 using sed when trying to print matching expression

Tags: sed, backreference

Before I start, I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637799/sed-error-invalid-reference-1-on-s-commands-rhs) question, but it seems the solution was that they were not escaping the parentheses in their regex. I'm getting the same error, but I'm not grouping a regex. What I want to do is find all names/usernames in a lastlog file and return the UNs ONLY.

What I have:

```
    s/^[a-z]+ |^[a-z]+[0-9]+/\1/p
```

I've seen many solutions that show how to do it in awk, which is great for future reference, but I want to do it using sed.

Edit for example input:

```
    dzhu             pts/15   n0000d174.cs.uts Wed Feb 17 08:31:22 -0600 2016
    krobbins                                   **Never logged in**
    js24                                       **Never logged in**
```

Comment: What do you think `\1` is for?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at [5.7 Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html).

Comment: including small sample input and expected output would help us clarify your thinking. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use backreferences (such as `\1`) if you do not have any capture groups in the first part of your substitution command.

Assuming you want the first word in the line, here's a command you can run:

```
sed -n 's/^\s*\(\w\+\)\s\?.*/\1/p'
```

Explanation:

- `-n` suppresses the default behavior of sed to print each line it processes
- `^\s*` matches the start of the line followed by any number of whitespace
- `\(\w\+\)` captures one or more word characters (letters and numbers)
- `\s\?.*` matches one or zero spaces, followed by any number of characters.  This is to make sure we match the whole word in the capture group
- `\1` replaces the matched line with the captured group
- The `p` flag prints lines that matched the expression.  Combined with `-n`, this means only matches get printed out.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you edit your post with a formatted version of that?  I can't tell where newlines should go in the comment and I don't want to assume.

Comment: Edited.  I hope it's what you're looking for.